# Unable to enter text after selecting the already text in search bar

Tags: javascript, angular, regex, validation, input

I applied some regex on input for restricting input value.
rule of input is user cannot type more than 3 characters in input field but when user typed three characters in input so when selecting all characters it not allowing to type again after selecting whole typed text. as you can see in stackblitz example which I created.
[here it is what I tried](https://angular-ivy-amuz4r.stackblitz.io)

typescript code

```
@ViewChild("searchText", { static: true }) public searchText: ElementRef;
  AAA = /^[a-zA-Z]{0,3}$/g;
  flight = /^[0-9]{0,4}$/g

  public validateFlightConnectionRules(e) {
    let searchTextLen = this.searchText.nativeElement.value.length;
    const val = ((this.searchText.nativeElement.value.match(this.flight) && (searchTextLen < 4)) || e.key === "Backspace")
    || (this.searchText.nativeElement.value.match(this.AAA) && (searchTextLen < 3));
    return val;
  }
```

html code

```
<input #searchText
type="text" class="text-line form-control clr-input-text" (keydown)="validateFlightConnectionRules($event)"/>
```

[image: it's what I applied validation]

[image: it's what user unable to type text again when select already typed text in the field]

also I need apply any special character validation through regex. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you include your code within this StackOverflow post? (the StackBlitz link isn't loading in my region). But you should be able to apply client-side validation using the [`pattern`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/pattern) attribute of an input field, which accepts a RegEx and works cross-browser.

Comment: Include minimal, reproducible example in your question, showing what you've tried so far and explaining what specifically isn't working as expected. Without this info, your question isn't answerable and may be closed.

Comment: @Lissy93 code added what I tried so far.

Comment: @Lissy93 
1) what happening is when I applied validation that user cannot type more than 3 characters it's working as expected. (this is working fine)

2) but once user type 3 characters in to the field and when try to select already typed text and try to again type other characters it not allowing. (It should not happen)

Comment: as per your code, it should allow your to delete the selected text pressing `Backspace`, is that working?

Comment: @GrafiCode yes when user hit backspace it's allowing to delete text but when user select all text and try to enter another characters it's not happening.

Comment: @GrafiCode any luck?

Comment: @Lissy93 any luck?

Comment: unable to see the code in provided stackblitz example, please provide code link

Comment: inside your validation function, maybe you can first check if text is entirely selected, with this: `let isAllSelected = (this.searchText.nativeElement.value.substring(this.searchText.nativeElement.selectionStart,this.searchText.nativeElement.selectionEnd).length == this.searchText.nativeElement.value.value.length)`

Comment: `if` that condition is `true` you should return whatever key the user pressed, `else` you should execute the rest: `const val = .....;` and `return val;`

Comment: @GrafiCode, thanks it's working fine. one more problem I need to resolve is that currently input field is accepting special characters which I need to stop user to type any special characters.